# Add generics dynamically to existing property

Tags: c#

Lets assume we have a property like:

```
private Action<String> actions= null;
```

Is there a way to actually change the "<>" part of the variable?

For example I would like to change the actions to contain two string inputs instead of one, for example:

```
private Action<String, String> actions= null;
```

Any way to do this, if so then how? Maybe with reflection?

Comment: In what context? Can you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: not sure what you're asking. Do you have a compiled assembly or what?

Comment: @NicoSchertler im trying. Let me try and edit.

Comment: Let me know if this questions is rubbish xD

Comment: If you want to "rename" this field from `Action<string>` to `Action<string, string>` just select it and click `ctrl + r` twice. But if you want to modify this at runtime .. I think it's almost impossible.

Comment: @m.rogalski damn, thought it could be done with reflection. It would be bad practice anways though : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that what you are asking for cannot be done.  Actually, it does not make sense.  The notion that you came up with, to dynamically add a generic argument to a type, is rather, eh, how to put it, psyhedelic.  (So, suppose you could dynamically change it; what would you do with it?  How would you invoke it, when any existing code that uses it expects it to have only one generic argument?)

The good news is that you should not need to do anything of that sort, because there already exists an `Action<String,String>`.

Comment: Yep and there is actually a reason I really need to set those dynamically. I noticed its really weird so It seems im on the wrong track or need a change in design.

Comment: There is a class of questions here on stackoverflow that fall under the "X/Y problem" category.  (http://xyproblem.info/)  Yours may be one of them.  You might be better off explaining what you originally wanted to accomplish, and asking how to accomplish it, rather than coming up with a wild idea of how your original task could be accomplished, and asking whether the wild idea would work.

Comment: I agree with you. Ill go into more detail once im at home.